# Create oracle trigger to send email on update of column

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to send an email on the update of inv_qoh, when inventory qoh falls below 3, an email sends with the item_id(which is in the same table) and the item_desc(from a different table, linked from item_id). This is my latest attempt of the trigger and the error is improper trigger syntax. Any help is appreciated.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Item_Out_of_Stock
AFTER UPDATE OF INV_QOH ON INVENTORY 
FOR EACH ROW
SELECT I.ITEM_ID, O.ITEM_DESC
FROM INVENTORY I, ITEM O
WHERE I.INV_QOH < 3 AND I.ITEM_ID = O.ITEM_ID;

BEGIN
  SEND_EMAIL(I.ITEM_ID, O.ITEM_DESC);
END;
/
```

Comment: move your select into the begin/end block.

Comment: try this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281861/oracle-db-suggestion-for-email-trigger

Comment: Are you sure to send an email by a trigger? What happens if the user makes a `ROLLBACK` after update? The update does not apply but the mail is send out anyway.

Comment: Further to @Wernfried's comment, note that Oracle may fire the trigger more than once for a given row in running the update. You will probably want to make sure that `send_email` is transactional (i.e. it won't send the email unless the calling statement is committed).

Comment: Is `item_id` a unique identifier for `inventory`? If so, you don't even need the query on `inventory` in the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.   I moved the select into an implicit for loop so I don't have to define variables or select INTO.  But it's a trigger "for each row" so only one rowcount will result.

```
create or replace trigger item_out_of_stock
    after update of inv_qoh
    on inventory
    for each row
begin
    for x in (select i.item_id, o.item_desc
                from inventory i, item o
               where i.inv_qoh < 3 and i.item_id = o.item_id) loop
        send_email (x.item_id, x.item_desc);
    end loop;
end;
/
```

This works doubly well since if the item is not < 3, 0 rowcount will occur and the anonymous block will not be run.