# How to send email from trigger, when our condition match on table in oracle?

Tags: oracle, triggers

Let's say, we would like to be informed via email when more than 200 records exist in the specific table of the Schema in the database.

Whenever this situation occurs, automatically trigger will execute and send an alert to a registered email address with Message.

Comment: I feel like this answer from 2012 covers it pretty well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281861/oracle-db-suggestion-for-email-trigger

Comment: Also this does not really sound like you want a trigger, but a DBMS_SCHEDULER job.

Comment: No, it doesn't really resolve my problem. I was expecting a solution from the trigger.